# Event Listener for Dynamic Form Zebra Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic, datepicker

I'm currently working with a code which will add additional form elements to my form, and will add a datepicker.
I've added an 'event listener' (thanks to Chandler Zwolle's script here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767578/1025961) to my existing code, but am having some difficulty in getting the datepicker to work with the form elements.  The console.log call seems to be working within the 'event listener' code, yet the datepicker isn't.

(Note: In addition to the 2 special Zebra_Datepicker files (https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/blob/master/public/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js) and (https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/blob/master/public/css/default.css), I have also been using 2 different versions of JQuery, with the 'noConflict' command.  Jquery 1.10.2 for the dynamically added form element code, and Jquery 2.1.3 for the Zebra Datepicker.  The version on my site behaves the same way as the one on this fiddle does, although, I'm not sure how to add the second version in JSFiddle.)

Thanks for any help.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/buck1115/s9pkc214/).

I've included my code, below.

A. HTML form

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td><button type="button" id="add-btn">Add Class Year</button></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="class_yr">
      <td class="FormLabel" width="100px"><strong>Class Year*</strong></td>
      <td width="100px"><input type="text" id="ClassYear_1" name="ClassYear_1" class="ClassYear" value="2004" tabindex="4" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

B. JS code

```
//var numeric = $(this).attr('id').match(/(\d+)/)[1] 
$(".ClassYear").each(function() {
    num = parseInt(this.id.split("_")[1], 10);
    id_string_prefix = "#ClassYear";
    id_string_combined = id_string_prefix.concat(num);

    $(id_string_combined).off();
    console.log(id_string_combined);

    // Re-add event handler for all matching elements
    $(id_string_combined).on("click", function() {
        // Handle event.
        $(id_string_combined).Zebra_DatePicker({
            view: 'years',
            readonly_element: true
        });
    });


});

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Call our function to setup initial listening
    RefreshSomeEventListener();


    function clone2() {
        var $cloned = $('table tr.class_yr:last').clone();
        var $oldIndex_name = $cloned.find('input').attr('name').match(/\d+/); //
        var $oldIndex_id = $cloned.find('input').attr('id').match(/\d+/); //
        var $newValue = $cloned.find('input').val('');
        //
        var newIndex_name = parseInt($oldIndex_name, 10) + 1;
        var newIndex_id = parseInt($oldIndex_id, 10) + 1;
        //console.log(newIndex_name);
        $cloned.find('input').each(function() {
            var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace($oldIndex_name, newIndex_name);
            $(this).attr('name', newName);
        });
        $cloned.find('input').each(function() {
            var newId = $(this).attr('id').replace($oldIndex_id, newIndex_id);
            $(this).attr('id', newId);
        });
        $cloned.insertAfter('table tr.class_yr:last');
        //console.log('hello');
    }
    $('#add-btn').click(function() {
        clone2();
        //console.log('hello');


        // Refresh our listener, so the new element is taken into account
        RefreshSomeEventListener();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note Github is not a CDN. In your fiddle the way you have added the external files is wrong. You need to include the raw URL of the Github file. So change `https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/blob/master/public/css/default.css` to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/master/public/css/default.css` and `https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/blob/master/public/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js` to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/master/public/javascript/zebra_datepicker.js`.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  When I pasted the URLs you provided, I did get a warning, but ignored that.  Not to side track too much, but would that type of link cause the example script in JSFiddle not to fire?

Comment: The JSFiddle has been updated to reflect the URL changes suggested above.